# Why does this code fail to work when being called in a popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, shopify

I wanted in my store product pages to have a gallery button that opens up a gallery of pictures of that product they are looking to buy. Only problem is that the popup button cant seem to load in the content I want to show for some reason. I know that these popups work since it works successfully with loading in sketchfab iframes of models like shown below.

[image: Image of "see in 3D" button]

[image: Image of "see in 3D" button working]

Only issue now is that the popup button for my gallery does the following shown below...

[image: Popup button for gallery before pressed]

[image: Popup button for gallery after pressed]

Through a lot of testing I have discovered that the photo gallery embed will only work if the popup is quickly opened before the web page is loaded. Although this is true once the popup is closed and reopened it is then broken again. Below is an image of the embed working in the popup.

[image: Image of photo embed working]

Through more testing I have also tested if the code can run inside the product description of my store. In doing so I have found out that it can run inside the product description. See the image below showing that it is working

[image: Image of embed running inside product description]

knowing all this, the only issue would have to do with both the google photos embed, and the popup code and how they work together. The popup codes are found at the following link. they are made by dimsemenov.

[Popup codes I use](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup)

I believe as an assumption the issue causing this is that this embed is a google photos displayer that constantly needs to be refreshed and updated as it is synced with google photos. What I know for a fact is with the way my popups are coded, they are loaded in when the page is loaded and are not refreshed or updated, and are only updated when the page is reloaded. I know this because if I change the code for inside the popup, and then after saving changes open a popup the changes arn't reflected inside until I refresh the entire page. In saying this though.. when I open my sketchfab iframe it does have the loading bar showing as though it is loading off sketchfab site, I cant seem to understand if this is the problem, why my photo embed cant do the same. This is only an assumption and am not sure if this is causing the problem. However if it is the problem is there a way to fix this issue. below is the embed google photos code used for one of my products.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/publicalbum@latest/embed-ui.min.js" async></script>
<div class="pa-carousel-widget" style="width:100%; height:480px; display:none;"
  data-link="https://photos.app.goo.gl/KvdTmPLrewaZ4VvWA"
  data-title="Shirai Ryu"
  data-description="10 new photos added to shared album">
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dDpV4uY9zN6x742KmOzaE5ZxDdJlU6TVD4NnhsyTIw6vFuhzLpxDGDGal3JvvsiGDGZyi7t2eeE4RwjbfvkNyf9Av8-yDSjXXs-Xtlm9CXkytft1CJg9ZN6XwCTy7xMd0ek0qrrXKA=w1920-h1080"></object>
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/G8CDlUSGKAcJwbMNyVBPM8mfd6Iq6XlFP_3ryqhrNvolSPJYNckZwpCpmTfGatMGxtImKJTkQO_tBXAzFJQ2kgDtffMA8x7Dx-bE5GF12b7JuEkyUO7KvGJq7OvLk4hxtAJ3PaD1yw=w1920-h1080"></object>
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Lt_cMOBt1Ua3bOTomjIQL4Rrldt3aGzKXvlVygFwSth5ObrkulhAhhSOnsZrgru4ac1_2ZQkAst-7NqZsyAHDnR7QHlYhptWVscK4pm5RKH22K3dZbr0eLdeU6nozBZl5jD-RfSTLQ=w1920-h1080"></object>
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/3Eh-1UUWg2Ny3flhQkUqbw9P8zO4_XzIfuyH0KmRNSz8JvX0pGdGYvhgs1r_LuFhPdJs9pmjAce2fyttsqLZVfC1pPtluRNPu1kmOc9VxwJnsPgXpnLdthyR1ckOmcjArDMep1VIKg=w1920-h1080"></object>
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/alnf2b0Ug47vNxihL-i_bxhV-H-o3fuHGS1F0LICzQjdejJwWF8kUPsZp0BjTKFfHhPAgPJau0khVpnTk5RaI8z1PDGO411-4BwHPTPEnAxRRhDT3MyW2IsmwxpTStCNoeS9upuiiw=w1920-h1080"></object>
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/i-10hdpYEH6dZ-hAEMRUr2X-xNgFlIwK93bh0lb2Fc-9W15NFksRSEQePv3com6wUzCJt--x9rtbcLO35Ox7diPwT7lhbRKOL8-DD4KVdZDoC5BYJXbbxu-ADxAxY-T_nEUsz6Jh4A=w1920-h1080"></object>
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Zj9I78oiH12745U5sHJteoSap9KEL8pNrUIWfwtG1YspZ9taxcMbSRn2UCY-GbxqJn5h51yZIOpb708JqBV1eQuzwSxTNfCmNB9UJqZxJfehCgJ2Uo4RfF-RVctGxC4yrie93necMQ=w1920-h1080"></object>
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/1NNepe283WSYo_8pJX5sloiwcEy2uE8MMGi4V_bLHoMV-By19oX4XTmt6sVHFYyt7-2M3LInsXmyZmQ0RlQst3kiQmt2_fNU9cljFxJdPHJwYVr0NRY1aGsg0ky7H0RQ3YTfir8lSQ=w1920-h1080"></object>
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/7eoT9bKBkDDndxTHD6hDTydt9cd2G_Rl40Yy_r3m_PvQ8GB7w5lPLRQ7da8zNy4u2nU0UFgc2LSrSlO6o4qdAN6UmEkz7CsJ8lO-zVl_L5-bfSye3tItl0U4x1VBnV2yXEspbAxOBQ=w1920-h1080"></object>
  <object data="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/uPt0BhapfibUCEaEg2X0Quk1C5cvCFYYst10CHcTNDb-NWlmr4rdt7aADO8jrQLrPONVb0vf8nMHxnhxcjmtd5NQlFESyacuifQTTexhHyh8N3RWDtCOP5xZNpl8t4cga8UcQpbRlg=w1920-h1080"></object>
</div>
```

If it helps here is more code, which is just showing the position where I have the embed placed within my popup. It is called in as {{ description_arr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZAEc.jpg) }}, from my product description. I am using Magnific Popup for my popups.

```
<div id="Image-Gallery" class="mfp-hide">


  <div class="row">
  <div class="gallerycolumn"></div>
  <div class="gallerycolumn"></div>
</div>


  <div class="row">
  <div class="galleryleft" style="background-color:#000000;"> 

 {{ description_arr[1] }}    





  </div>
  <div class="galleryright" style="background-color:#000000;">
    <div class="acerill-custom-form" data-form-id="ca3d163c-517f-4dda-8e8c-202a1cb2e3dc"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://custom-forms-client.acerill.com/js/custom-forms-v2.js"></script>
  </div>
</div>

</div>


<style>
#image-gallery {
  border: 0px #555 solid;
  background-color: #ffffff;

  max-width: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;


}
</style>
```

I greatly appreciate all the support.

Kind Regards

Nicolas Murdaca

Comment: I highly recommend you put up a working snippet illustrating the issue to make debugging easier

Comment: I dont think having it in a snippet would help. I already know that the popup isn't an issue and it works perfectly fine. It is a very complex popup which has "a lot" of code running it, and has been installed into my store. where things go in different places You can find the codes for this popup online by looking up Magnific Popup. I also know that my strategy for calling code for say my sketchfab iframe also works successfully meaning there are no issues there. I am using the exact same way for doing both my popups. My sketchfab iframe seems to work, so nothing is wrong with codes.

Comment: Only problem would be something to do with the google photos embed, and how its code would act within the popup. I'm assuming that its got something to do with the popups way of functioning and how that differs to a normal web page. If I put the google photos embed on just a webpage it works perfectly, but once inside a popup it doesn't work.

Comment: I have updated the post above...

Comment: Never found an answer to this issue, but I found a solution by using a different site. Just make all your albums using this website and they work.

https://www.cincopa.com/